# PHP Preg match all m3u8 to parse into array

Tags: php, parsing, preg-match-all, m3u8

So I need to parse m3u8 string into array. However in particular case it was cut too early.

This is the line:

```
preg_match_all('/#EXTINF:(.+?)[,]\s?(.+?)[\r\n]+?((?:https?|rtmp):\/\/(?:\S*?\.\S*?)(?:[\s)\[\]{};"\\'<]|\.s$))/', $input_lines, $output_array);
```

if the URL sample is "normal" it will parse properly:

```
    #EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="https://someimage.url/logo.png" group-title="TV",Channel (backup)
    https://streaming.url/m3u/channel.m3u8
```

will parse into:

```
array(4
    0   =>  array(1
        0   =>  #EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="https://someimage.url/logo.png" group-title="TV",Channel (backup)
https://streaming.url/m3u/channel.m3u8
    )
    1   =>  array(1
        0   =>  -1 tvg-logo="https://someimage.url/logo.png" group-title="TV"
    )
    2   =>  array(1
        0   =>  Channel (backup)
    )
    3   =>  array(1
        0   =>  https://streaming.url/m3u/channel.m3u8
    )
)
```

However if there is a bracket in URL it will not parse completely (missing the .m3u8):

```
    #EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="https://someimage.url/logo.png" group-title="TV",Channel (backup)
    https://streaming.url/m3u/channel(bu).m3u8
```

will parse into:

```
array(4
    0   =>  array(1
        0   =>  #EXTINF:-1 tvg-logo="https://someimage.url/logo.png" group-title="TV",Channel (backup)
https://streaming.url/m3u/channel(bu)
    )
    1   =>  array(1
        0   =>  -1 tvg-logo="https://someimage.url/logo.png" group-title="TV"
    )
    2   =>  array(1
        0   =>  Channel (backup)
    )
    3   =>  array(1
        0   =>  https://streaming.url/m3u/channel(bu)
    )
)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't actually see a problem statement here.  What is the input and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```php
$re = '/#EXTINF:(.+?)[,]\s?(.+?)[\r\n]+?((?:https?|rtmp):\/\/(?:\S*?\.\S*?)(?:[\s\[\]{};"\\\\\'<]|\.s$))/';
```

Or check solution online here: [Regex101.com...](https://regex101.com/r/5LnEwJ/1)