# PHP Fetching URL bellow expression from file

Tags: php, regex, strpos

i'm trying to fetch a URL from a file but can't really find a way to make it work.

I've looked into regex and explode and strpos but can't find a way, I could use some help.

This is the piece of code i'm currently using for extracting the channelname;

```
foreach($fileContent as $line) {
    if((strpos($line, 'group-title') == true) && (strpos($line, 'tvg-name="#####') == false) 
        && ((strpos($line, '|NL|') == true) || (strpos($line, 'group-title="BE"') == true))) {
        $m3uChannelName = substr($line, strrpos($line, ',') + 1);
        $m3uChannelName = rtrim($m3uChannelName);
        $m3uChannelName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $m3uChannelName);
        $sql_insertFileValue = "INSERT INTO epg_m3ufile (m3uChannelName) VALUES ('" . $m3uChannelName . "')";
        $resultM3U = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_insertFileValue);
        
        if (!empty($resultM3U)) {
            $affectedRowM3u ++;
        }else{
            $error_message = mysqli_error($conn) . "\n";
        }
        
    }
}
```

this is some of the content in de file;

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="|NL| NPO 1 HD" tvg-logo="http://134.255.234.197/logos/npo1.png" group-title="NL| NEDERLAND",|NL| NPO 1 HD
http://localhost.dummy.proof:80/123456/654321/0123
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="|NL| NPO 2 HD" tvg-logo="http://134.255.234.197/logos/npo2.png" group-title="NL| NEDERLAND",|NL| NPO 2 HD
http://localhost.dummy.proof:80/654321/123456/3210
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="|NL| NPO 3 HD" tvg-logo="http://134.255.234.197/logos/npo3.png" group-title="NL| NEDERLAND",|NL| NPO 3 HD
http://localhost.dummy.proof:80/416352/524163/0231
```

What I would like to do is to modify the foreach so that I can import the url aswell as the channelname to my database, but I can't seem to make it work cause the url is on the line bellow the strposs check.

I'm hoping you guys can help me / tell me how to achive this.

I've tried this solution, but couldn't get it to work [PHP Preg match all m3u8 to parse into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66524313/php-preg-match-all-m3u8-to-parse-into-array)

Kind regards,
Patrick

Comment: `== true` shoukd be `!== FALSE` see https://3v4l.org/ZSJUY

Comment: Or starting with php8, you can use [`str_contains`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) that returns a boolean. At worst, you can call the A-Team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a pattern with 2 capture groups to get the value of tvg-name and the last url:

```
^#EXTINF:.*?\btvg-name="([^"]*)".*\R(https?:\/\/\S*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `#EXTINF:` Match literally
- `.*?` Match as least as possible characters
- `\btvg-name=` A word boundary, match `tvg-name=`
- `"([^"]*)"` Capture in **group 1** what is between double quotes
- `.*\R` Match the rest of the line and a newline
- `(https?:\/\/\S*)` Capture the last url in g**roup 2**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qmJpgU/1)

Example:

```
$re = '/^#EXTINF:.*?\btvg-name="([^"]*)".*\R(https?:\/\/\S*)/m';
$str = '#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="|NL| NPO 1 HD" tvg-logo="http://134.255.234.197/logos/npo1.png" group-title="NL| NEDERLAND",|NL| NPO 1 HD
http://localhost.dummy.proof:80/123456/654321/0123
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="|NL| NPO 2 HD" tvg-logo="http://134.255.234.197/logos/npo2.png" group-title="NL| NEDERLAND",|NL| NPO 2 HD
http://localhost.dummy.proof:80/654321/123456/3210
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="|NL| NPO 3 HD" tvg-logo="http://134.255.234.197/logos/npo3.png" group-title="NL| NEDERLAND",|NL| NPO 3 HD
http://localhost.dummy.proof:80/416352/524163/0231';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
foreach($matches as $m) {
    echo $m[1] . PHP_EOL . $m[2] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
|NL| NPO 1 HD
http://localhost.dummy.proof:80/123456/654321/0123
|NL| NPO 2 HD
http://localhost.dummy.proof:80/654321/123456/3210
|NL| NPO 3 HD
http://localhost.dummy.proof:80/416352/524163/0231
```

Comment: Absolute legend! that did the trick.
Only had to change a additional line from file($inputFile); to file_get_contents($inputFile); 

file puts the info into an array and I needed a string for your sollution! 
Thanks